# Index was outside the bounds of the String array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I have this test code in VB:

```
Dim st As New ScheduledTasks("\\webserver")
Dim tasknames() As String = st.GetTaskNames
ListBox1.Items.Add(tasknames(1))

st.Dispose()
```

When i run it i get an error on line:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(tasknames(1))
```

***Index was outside the bounds of the array.***

Does anyone have any suggestions what im doing wrong?

Comment: You're assuming the `GetTaskNames` returns 2 or more values, and that assumption is incorrect? Beyond that, there's not much we can say because we have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's likely anything you're trying to do is not groundbreaking, so post more code and show us the items for st.GetTaskNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tasknames` must contain at least 2 items for your code to work. (Note that arrays are 0-based, so you start counting at 0)

You have to check whether it really contains that amount:

```
If tasknames.Length >= 2
Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(tasknames(1))
End If
```

Comment: That did the trick. I Upgraded it so it doesen't trow next exception. If tasknames.Length >= 2 Then
            For i = 1 To tasknames.Length - 1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(tasknames(i))
            Next
        End If

Comment: @user3360710 - with your `For` loop, you're still missing out one item - as Patrick said, arrays are 0-based. The first item in the array is at 0, but your `For` loop starts at 1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for pointing this out again. I think most people who start programming are unaware of this.

Comment: Yes, I allready changed i to 0 before I posted the answer just forgot that clipboard had 1.